# Any good iPhone/iPad apps for brewing?

Tags: brewing, recipe-formulation

Looking for recipe formulation, IBU/SG calculations, brewing timers, inventory control, etc.

A bonus if the app renders my iPhone waterproof(wortproof).

Comment: Should be Community Wiki

Comment: Did anybody else think, upon seeing the title, "iPhone and iPad apps are non-fermentable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brew Pal](http://www.brewpal.info/) is an excellent program for storing recipes and doing some calculations for things like IBU and gravity, which is what I use it for.  I purchased it the day after I bought my iPod, just because I wanted to support homebrew apps, turns out I love it and use it on every brew day.

It allows easy email export of BeerXML, which makes storing recipes off the iPod easy.

It's also $0.99, which is not a good reflection of its value, I'd pay $4.99.

Comment: BrewPal doesn't report your estimated gravity correctly, which is a pretty huge error in any sort of brewing software: http://ianwhitney.com/hopwise/2011/04/10/brew-pal-for-the-iphone-just-doesnt-work/

Answer (score 5):

[Kent Place Software](http://www.kentplacesoftware.com/index.html) produces some useful brewing apps for iPhone and Mac. They also have an iPad version in the works. I've used their Beer Alchemy Mac software for awhile.

[image: Beer Alchemy Touch] [BeerAlchemy Touch](http://www.kentplacesoftware.com/products/BeerAlchemyTouch.html) is their iPhone version. It's a bit pricey at $14.99, but provides wireless syncing between the mac version and the iPhone version, which is really handy.

[image] [Brew Math](http://www.kentplacesoftware.com/products/BrewMath.html) is also handy, and only $2.99. Not as fully featured as BeerAlchemy, but is described as a "powerful brewing calculator in your pocket."

Hope that helps!

Comment: I use BeerAlchemy Touch extensively during my brew day, and love it.  I have a few gripes about the number of taps I have to make when moving between a recipe screen and the calculators, but otherwise, very handy, and I don't have to schlep my laptop to the garage.

Comment: BeerAlchemy for iPad has been out for a while ($9.99), and the iPhone version has gotten a lot cheaper at $4.99. I use the iPhone version all the time, and love it.

Answer (score 3):

My Brew works great.  It let's you track your brews, calculates abw/abv/calories, provides overall brew stats, brew timers, etc.
[iTunes Link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-brew/id338354012?mt=8)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the party, but the best one I've used is [iBrewMaster](http://ibrewmaster.com). It's currently  available for $7.99 for the iPod/iPhone edition and $10.99 for the iPad edition. Rather than regurgitate all the features, take a look in the iTunes store [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibrewmaster/id315820829?mt=8) and [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibrewmaster-ipad-edition/id363957954?mt=8) for more details. Overall, it has worked the best for me in managing the process from start to finish. I especially like the alerts functionality when I have multiple batches going at once.

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Malty has a iphone app for yeast pitching rates. Available at www.mrmalty.com Cost is $4.99.

Comment: $4.99 for just pitching rate calculations!!! Holy cow, does that app do anything else????

Comment: gives starter measurements. you can use the free version on www.mtmalty.com though.

Answer (score -1):

Not that I am aware of, but I would be surprised if there was nothing, if so sounds like you've found my next pet project.

You should be able to run some of the javascript based calculators that are all over the web through the phone, but it might be a bit of a pain.

Comment: Downvoted because there are numerous apps available currently as well as when OP asked question.

Comment: and there's no requirement to post *something* if you don't actually have an answer ;-)